# sqlAlchemy: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to solve this for hours now, I've read through a few stack overflows, the official SQL alchemy documentation and watched youtube tutorials and it's all the same code as mine.

I have 3 tables - Users and Roles, and user_role which joins them.

I keep getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship 
Users.role - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'user_role'.  Ensure that referencing 
columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' 
expressions.
```

My code:

```
engine = create_engine('***',
connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format('flaskProject')})

Base = declarative_base(engine)
Base.query = db.session.query_property()

user_role = Table('user_role', Base.metadata,
Column('userId', Integer, ForeignKey("Users.id")),
Column('roleId', Integer, ForeignKey("Roles.id")))


class Users(UserMixin, Base):
__tablename__ = 'users'
__table_args__ = {'schema': 'flaskProject'}

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
username = Column(String)
email = Column(String)
password_hash = Column(String)

role = relationship("Roles", secondary = user_role)



class Roles(Base):

__table_args__ = {'schema': 'flaskProject'}
__tablename__ = 'roles'


id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String)
```

Comment: Your `users` and `roles` tables live in the `flaskProject` schema but your `user_role` table does not. You might want to add `schema="flaskProject"` to your `Table()` call and define your foreign key declarations like `Column("userId", Integer, ForeignKey("flaskProject.users.id")),`

Comment: @GordThompson I just tried your idea, but I still get the same error

`user_role = Table('user_role', Base.metadata,
    Column('userId', Integer, ForeignKey("flaskProject.Users.id")),
    Column('roleId', Integer, ForeignKey("flaskProject.Roles.id"))
    ,schema='flaskProject')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issues with my secondary table - I was missing the schema in the table definition, had to add the schema to the foreign keys, and column names are case-sensitive

```
user_role = Table('user_role', Base.metadata,
Column('userid', Integer, ForeignKey('flaskProject.users.id')),
Column('roleid', Integer, ForeignKey('flaskProject.roles.id'))
,schema='flaskProject')
```